# Pronunciation of "status", "bomb", "database" and "Wednesday"

Tags: pronunciation

How are the following words pronounced? I always get confused on pronunciation. I put the pronunciation I think is correct next to the words:

Status - (Stat-us with Stat rhyming with mat)

Bomb - Is the "B" at the end silent or pronounced?

Database - Is it Dat-a-base or Day-ta-base

Wednesday - Is it Wens-day or Wed-ness-day?

Comment: about data: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10155/data-pronunciation-dayta-or-dahta  Also, please ask one question a time

Comment: @Theta30 Pronunciation for most words is genref.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Status*: 'Stat-us' and 'State-us' are both used

*Bomb*: Always a silent b, pronounced as 'Bomm'

*Wednesday*: Usually I hear this as 'Wens-day'; on occasion I have heard it pronounced as 'Weddens-day'. I do not believe it is ever pronounced 'Wed-ness-day'

Comment: Nice! Thanks! What about Database?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the audio pronunciation on an online dictionary like www.dictionary.com. It is very common for different pronunciations to exist for the same word. The American and British pronunciations of the same words can be quite different.