# Is day-ta more common in the South or the North of the US?

Tags: pronunciation, dialects

So I've read that dah-ta is more common in the US than in other places, but is day-ta or dah-ta more common to hear in the South?  I haven't been able to find that out for sure.

Comment: I don't know if people have done studies on this. A related question with answers that focus on international differences: [Data pronunciation: “dayta” or “data”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10155)

Comment: Depends.  Are you talking about a piece of information or a female offspring?

Comment: I agree with @sumelic that this question has been answered generally. As a scientist who has lived, worked, and traveled through most of the U.S., I can say that dahta is very rare in my field. It also appears not to have had a detailed regional analysis, at least where I am used to looking for such: http://www4.uwm.edu/FLL/linguistics/dialect/maps.html