# Are there any dialects of English that pronounce "regalia" as "rəˈɡälyə"?

Tags: pronunciation, dialects

Google tells me that it sounds like this:

> rəˈɡālyə

Other resources say:

- merriam-webster.com: /ri-ˈgāl-yə/
- dictionary.com: /ri-gey-lee-uh/, /-geyl-yuh/
- dictionary.cambridge.org: /rɪˈɡeɪl·jə/
- macmillandictionary.com: /rɪˈɡeɪljə/
- oxforddictionaries.com: /rəˈɡālyə/

For some reason I want to say it like this:

> rəˈɡälyə

Is there anyone who knows of any communities out there that commonly mispronounce it this way?

Comment: OK. Yeah I'll definitely do that, but I'd still like to know if anyone knows of any communities out there that commonly mispronounce it the way I did.

Comment: With this sort of question, it is reasonable to expect OP to offer pronunciations given by several dictionaries.

Comment: OK. Sure thing.    
  
merriam-webster.com: /ri-ˈgāl-yə/,    
  
dictionary.com: /ri-gey-lee-uh/, /-geyl-yuh/,    
  
dictionary.cambridge.org: /rɪˈɡeɪl·jə/,    
  
macmillandictionary.com: /rɪˈɡeɪljə/,    
  
oxforddictionaries.com: /rəˈɡālyə/

Comment: [Oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/es/traducir/ingles-espanol/regalia?searchDictCode=spanish-english) uses IPA. It is listed as /rəˈɡeɪljə/.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any community where "rəˈɡälyə" (IPA /rəˈgɑːljə/) has become an established pronunciation (it's not listed in any of the [OneLook](https://www.onelook.com/?w=regalia&ls=a)-indexed dictionaries), so I would avoid using it, and recommend pronouncing *regalia* to rhyme with "Australia" instead.

Some Latinate words spelled with the letter "a" show variation between "long" /eɪ/, "short" /æ/, and a "restored" quality /ɑː/, but this is highly dependent on the identity of the specific word. For example, /ɑː/ has become standard for whatever reason in the word *drama,* but seems to be pretty uncommon in *data* (see [Alex B.'s answer to "Data pronunciation: “dayta” or “dahta”?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/73841/77227)). There are sometimes differences between dialects: e.g. /eɪ/ in *dahlia* is more common in British English than in American English, according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dahlia).

I found a Reddit conversation that confirms that you are not the only person who has thought of using /ɑː/ in "regalia":

- > I'm guessing you say regahlia instead of regaylia just based on your taste. Is that true?

  –asphyxiate, Wed Aug 16 23:20:56 2017 UTC
- > I do say regahlia, you're right! I was sad when I realised that *azure* wasn't pronounced azooooerr; some words just taste better mispronounced.

  –sushideception, Wed Aug 16 23:56:34 2017 UTC

("[I have synesthesia, which allows me to taste words. AMA!](https://www.reddit.com/r/casualiama/comments/6u3jqq/i_have_synesthesia_which_allows_me_to_taste_words/)", casualiama Reddit)